# Neural network with validation and without validation are giving me two extremely different initial loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, sequential

In the code below, I am trying to run a simple neural network for regression purpose. The code works fine but when I change the **validation_split** from 0 to 0.3, the initial training loss are extremely different which should not be the case, they must be similar especially having **shuffle =True**.

```
model=tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32,activation="tanh", 
kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16,activation="tanh"))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=5,activation="linear"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(x=samples,y=target,batch_size=20,validation_split=0.3, 
epochs=100,shuffle=True, callbacks=[TrainValTensorBoard(write_graph=False)])
```

Train on 70 samples, validate on 30 samples

```
Epoch 1/100
70/70 [==============================]loss: 696.1112 - val_loss: 7073.7749
Epoch 2/100
70/70 [==============================]loss: 689.5668 - val_loss: 7038.8966
Epoch 3/100
70/70 [==============================]loss: 681.3793 - val_loss: 7001.0728
Epoch 4/100
70/70 [==============================]loss: 675.0622 - val_loss: 6962.4543
Epoch 5/100
70/70 [==============================]loss: 669.0066 - val_loss: 6924.7336
```

Results if validation_split=0

```
Epoch 1/100
100/100 [=============]loss: 2554.8586
Epoch 2/100
100/100 [=============]loss: 2532.5045
Epoch 3/100
100/100 [=============]loss: 2516.1542
Epoch 4/100
100/100 [=============]loss: 2501.7217
```

Comment: I am curious, what would you see if you try 0.1 or 0.01?

Comment: Both the `loss` in the 2nd code snippet and the `val_loss` in the 1st code snippet are different. The validation loss is greater than the training loss which is a sign of overfitting.

Comment: I don't understand why you are expecting the losses to be similar. Training on more data is going to be more difficult, hence you will have a bigger loss.